# Install android sdk without Android Studio in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, android-sdk-2.3

Here is how I installed my android sdk to run React Native on my Android phone:
Considering that Java and adb is already installed:

```sh
sudo apt update && sudo apt install android-sdk
```

This will add the environment variables:

```sh
echo 'export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/lib/android-sdk"
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/usr/lib/android-sdk"
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
' >> ~/.bashrc
```

We now need to install the missing sdkManager:

```sh
source ~/.bashrc
# Download the archive
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6609375_latest.zip
unzip commandlinetools-linux-6609375_latest.zip -d cmdline-tools
# Make the sdk directory writable
sudo chmod -R a+rw $ANDROID_HOME
# Merge bin with bin and tools with tools
mv cmdline-tools/tools/bin/* $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/
rm -rf cmdline-tools/tools/bin
mv cmdline-tools/tools/* $ANDROID_HOME/tools/
rm -rf cmdline-tools
# Accept the licences
yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME} --licenses
```

Now, Here is what I get when running `react-native run-android`:

```sh
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:installDebug'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/xxx/android/local.properties'.
```

Ok, I can set sdk.dir in local.properties and this works, but I don't want to do this in every single project I have to work with. Why is the `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` being ignored?

Comment: I never used `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`, and there's a local.properties file in every project I make.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107851/using-export-in-bashrc

Comment: @Nicolas when creating the project with `react-native init`, there is not.

Comment: you should be adding `bin` subfolders for `tools` and `platform-tools` to the `PATH` and it needs to be exported as well

Comment: @AlexP. Actually, it worked. I'm now having Could not find tools.jar. I'll check if I find the cause

Comment: Solved by reinstalling the jdk from openjdk. Thanks everyone !